# Dividing two numbers with more than 50 digits(max 200) algorithm

Tags: algorithm, divide

What is the best way to **divide** two numbers that have more than **50 digits**, but **less than 200**.

I have *structure* to represent a number:

```
struct number{

     int digit[MAX_SIZE]; // MAX_SIZE = 5;
     bool negative; // Is it negative or positive number
};
```

The problem that I face when trying to implement this algorithm is that, if I'm trying to divide a number *'n'* with a number *'m'* **(n > m)** that has more digits then you can store in a variable, how can you divide it ?

For example:
**1234567891234567891234567 / 12345678912345678**

My first guess is to do with **repeated subtractions**, but isn't that too slow?

Comment: How do you do it in elementary school? Pretend that you are an elementary school teacher and the computer is a rather dull student. See this for more ideas (which includes the long-division method I was alluding to): https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Division_algorithm

Comment: In addition to everything @JohnColeman said, it's also worth bearing in mind that this wheel has already been invented. If you're programming in C, use the [GMP library](https://gmplib.org/). Some higher-level languages like Python are quite happy working directly with arbitrarily large integers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think about how you do it by hand:

You calculate the most significant digit first. And if the numbers are great enough you do it by repeated subtraction, finding one digit at a time.

In your case:
The first number has 25 digits and the second number has 17 digits.

So you start with the digit corresponding to 1E8.

Here is some C-style pseudocode.

```
struct number n1 = 1234567891234567891234567;
struct number n2 = 12345678912345678;
int start = floor(log10(n1) - log10(n2));   // Position of most significant digit in answer
struct number result = 0;
int i,j;
struct number remainder = n1;

// Start with the most significant digit
for i = start to 0 {
  // Find the highest digit that gives a remainder >= 0
  for j = 9 to 0 step -1 {
    if (remainder - j * n2 * pow(10, i) >= 0) {
        // We found the digit!
        result = result + j * pow(10, i);
        remainder = remainder - j * n2 * pow(10, i);
        break; // Move on to the next digit
    }
  }
}
// We now have the result and the remainder.
```